# Changing source control workspace in Matlab for MSSCCI

Tags: matlab, version-control, msscci

I made the mistake of using the workspace I use for my visual studio projects when I set up Matlab's Team Foundation Server integration via MSSCCI. This is a problem because MSSCCI will forcefully convert the workspace from local to server, and this is undesirable for my visual studio projects.

Thus, to solve this problem, I created a separate server workspace just for Matlab, but I can't figure out how to switch Matlab to use the new workspace. This is obnoxious because any changes you make to the workspace (renaming, or moving the mapped Matlab directories) causes MSSCCI to throw a non-ending sequence of error messages. I have dug around the preference window in Matlab, but it doesn't have any option to do this.

How do I make Matlab switch to a new workspace?

Answer (score 0):

The only chance you get to configure source control server and workspace information is during the initial setup; once you have those settings committed Matlab doesn't have any interface to change it.

However, Matlab saves all this information in a simple text file, so we can just edit it ourselves. Open the file `%APPDATA%\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2014a\mw.scc` and you will see all your file mappings included in this text file. Simply do a search-and-replace to change the name of your old workspace to the new one. (Be sure to do this while Matlab is closed)

Note that once you change your workspace you should make sure that the mapped files are also moved to the new workspace (e.g. in Visual Studio); if you forget to do this you will be faced with repeated error messages from MSSCCI complaining about the directories being mapped to a different workspace.